# Signing out User with Devise is signing out the AdminUser as well

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, activeadmin

I am using Devise for my User model. I am also using ActiveAdmin which is using Devise as well for the AdminUser model.

I can sign in using an admin_user and a user independently of each other, but I have noticed if I sign out the User, the AdminUser is signed out as well. The same thing happens if I reverse it and sign out the AdminUser first.

What can I do to hopefully get around this?

routes.rb

```
devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
devise_for :users
get "dashboard/home"
```

ApplicationController

```
protected

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if resource.is_a?(User)
    stored_location_for(:user) || dashboard_home_path
  elsif resource.is_a?(AdminUser)
    stored_location_for(:admin_user) || admin_root_path(resource)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are looking for is a Devise configuration called `sign_out_all_scopes`

When a user signs out and it is set to true, all scopes are signed out for this user, both user and admin in your case.

In devise.rb search for sign_out_all_scopes and change its value to true.

Comment: I think you mean setting it to false. Since true is the default value.

When you set the value to `false` it will only sign out the current scope.